# How to add a page with a default active filter with products in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What I want to achieve is a page with products in it, But not all the products on my store. These products are filtered. I want this page to have a default active filter and the user doesn't have the ability to cancel the active filter.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcode on this page and achieve product listing. For e.g. [products ids="1, 2, 3, 4, 5"]

Here are few more shortcodes that woocommerce offers by default: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: Thank you so much, but,no products are showing in my page, i tried all kinds of short codes.

Comment: Then something should be wrong with your woocommerce installation or the way you are using it.

Comment: would you power me with the shortcode for the desired operation above?..i'm trying to list product according on a unique value for an attribute